# Mongodb server goes down, how to prevent Rails app from timing out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I'm using [central_logger](https://github.com/reedlaw/central_logger) to store logs from our Rails app in mongodb. When the mongo server went down recently our app started timing out on mongo inserts. How can I prevent Rails from timing out if the mongo server goes down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ruby driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver) supports timeouts like so

```
@conn = Connection.new("localhost", 27017, :pool_size => 5, :timeout => 5)
```

But the central_logger gem isn't using that. So you can either fork it to add that in there, or monkey-path the CentralLogger::MongoLogger.connect method

It [currently has](https://github.com/reedlaw/central_logger/blob/master/lib/central_logger/mongo_logger.rb)

```
def connect
    @mongo_connection ||= Mongo::Connection.new(@db_configuration['host'],
                                                @db_configuration['port'],
                                                :auto_reconnect => true).db(@db_configuration['database'])

    if @db_configuration['username'] && @db_configuration['password']
      # the driver stores credentials in case reconnection is required
      @authenticated = @mongo_connection.authenticate(@db_configuration['username'],
                                                      @db_configuration['password'])
    end
  end
```

You would need to [monkey-path](http://johnragan.wordpress.com/2010/02/22/safer-monkey-patching/) in :timeout=>5 (or whatever) to the Mongo::Connection.new

I would bet the author of central-logger would like to have this in there, so a fork and pull request would likely be welcome.

Comment: I saw that in the ruby driver README but wasn't sure how to use it. The README says "If implementing higher-level timeouts, using tools like Rack::Timeout, it's very important to call Mongo::Connection#close to prevent the subsequent operation from receiving the previous request." I'm using Rack::Timeout, so how should I call Mongo::Connection#close? I already have a fork of central_logger that makes it compatible with Heroku logging. I'll just add this to that fork.

Comment: @Reed G. Law: I would think @mongo_connection.close (or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [replica sets](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Sets) - so if the master goes down, it can failover automatically to one of the replicas.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the database insert should be fast, so you could work with the ruby timeout:

```
require 'timeout'
Timeout::timeout(0.2) do
  ... write to log server
end
```

this code will timeout and continue after 200 milliseconds in any case.