# ConnectionFailure using mongo in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have an app setup with Rails 3.1, Mongo 1.4.0, Mongoid 2.2.4.

What I am experiencing is this:

```
Mongo::ConnectionFailure: Failed to connect to a master node at localhost:27017
```

I've had this problem before, but it went away on a computer restart... this time it does not.
I don't understand, I didn't do anything. I just put my computer in sleep mode, went home and woke it up, then there it was.

Here is the output of `sudo mongod`

```
Fri Nov 25 21:47:14 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1963 port=27017          dbpath=/data/db/ 64-bit host=xxx.local
Fri Nov 25 21:47:14 [initandlisten] db version v2.0.0, pdfile version 4.5
Fri Nov 25 21:47:14 [initandlisten] git version: 695c67dff0ffc361b8568a13366f027caa406222
Fri Nov 25 21:47:14 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin erh2.10gen.cc 9.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 9.6.0: Mon Nov 24 17:37:00 PST 2008; root:xnu-1228.9.59~1/RELEASE_I386 i386 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_40
Fri Nov 25 21:47:14 [initandlisten] options: {}
Fri Nov 25 21:47:14 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
Fri Nov 25 21:47:14 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Fri Nov 25 21:47:15 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
Fri Nov 25 21:47:15 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

And I am able to connect with `mongo`in terminal.
After 2 hours of Googling I hope the competence of SOs community are able to figure this out.
Please, if you need more information about my app-setup just ask.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see is that the connection times out... that happens either after a long period of inactivity, or if you put your computer to sleep.

You can change / increase the timeout value, but this way you can't get rid of the connection timing out eventually.

Some MongoDB drivers allow to set :timeout => false , but Mongoid seems to still have problems with that
(see last 3 links in the list)

Hope this helps.

See also:

[Mongodb server goes down, how to prevent Rails app from timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870459/mongodb-server-goes-down-how-to-prevent-rails-app-from-timing-out)

[MongoDB: What is connection pooling and timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327416/mongodb-what-is-connection-pooling-and-timeout)

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver

---

[How can I query mongodb using mongoid/rails without timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018838/how-can-i-query-mongodb-using-mongoid-rails-without-timing-out)

http://groups.google.com/group/mongoid/browse_thread/thread/b5c94e7047b42f8a

https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/455

Comment: Thank you so much for this thorough answer!

Answer (score 2):

Try to change localhost to 127.0.0.1!